# Android SoundPool load() returning null

Tags: java, android, audio, multimedia

I'm working on an Android app and trying to use SoundPool to play some music in the background (I know MediaPlayer would be better for this, but I really want to figure out how to use this class since it's frustrating me). I'm trying to load two mp3 files using a static Music class and store their sound IDs in a HashMap so I can access them when they're ready to be used. However, putting them in a HashMap is giving me a NullPointerException.

```
public static void play(Context context, int resource) {
    if (sp == null) {
        sp = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        sp.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
                loaded = true;
            }
        });
        sounds.put(R.raw.main, sp.load(context, R.raw.main, 1));
        sounds.put(R.raw.game, sp.load(context, R.raw.game, 1));
        am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        float volume = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC) / am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        sp.play(sounds.get(resource), volume, volume, 0, -1, 1.0f);
    } else {
        float volume = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC) / am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        sp.play(sounds.get(resource), volume, volume, 0, -1, 1.0f);
    }
}
```

Specifically, I'm getting an NullPointerException on the line `sounds.put(R.raw.main, sp.load(context, R.raw.main, 1));`

I've tried using a while loop immediately after loading the sound files that simply loops until "loaded" is true, but that just results in the app hanging forever. Additionally, both mp3 files are 400 KB or less, so I don't think their sizes are an issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you remember to construct your `HashMap` (or whatever `sounds` is)?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
sounds.load(collection.getContext(), R.raw.main, 1);
```

Or this method

```
int sound_id = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("myownsound", "raw",
                                                     mContext.getPackageName());
soundPool.load(mContext, sound_id, 1);
```

Or Have a look at this link

**[Soundpool](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Media/SoundPoolDemo.htm)**

Comment: I don't see how the first suggestion would work, seeing as I don't have any variable called collection. I tried the second suggestion and got the same result as before. Thanks for the reply though.